# Google places api service is not woring in my android project

Tags: google-places-api

Google places api service is not woring in my android project.I have enabled api key.I am using server key to get places in autocompleteTextView. But I found error "This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console: Learn more: https://code.google.com/apis/console",
   "predictions" : []" 
    Always while debugging. Please any body help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google places api request denied error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652330/google-places-api-request-denied-error)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using the [Google Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/) from your Android app?  Have you considered using the [Google Places API for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/)?

Comment: Yes i considered. I have followed every step to generate key.