# Google places api request denied error

Tags: google-places-api

I am using google palces api for autocomplete textview in my android project. I have enabled the api key. I am using a server key but all the time I have this error when I call the service through a browser :

```
{
   "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console: Learn more: https://code.google.com/apis/console",
   "predictions" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

And same error in android debugger.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the error, you have to go to the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project), then open **APIs & auth** -> **APIs** and enable the **Google Places API Web Service** which include the **autocomplete** feature :

> Find detailed information about places across a wide range of categories. Backed by the same database used by Google Maps and Google+, the Google Places API Web Service features about 100 million businesses and points of interest that are updated frequently through owner-verified listings and user-moderated contributions. Key features include autocomplete, search, place picker, photos and add place.

[image]

Hope that can help.